# Reading words from text file into array

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to make a spell check program. I want to read the words from a dictionary file into an array, then compare words from another text file to that dictionary array, and finally print out any misspelled words. The problem I'm facing is that my scanner is reading the words as one long string. If you were to run the program, you would see that it shows the variable `word` as being the entire contents of the text file, and it only runs the binary search comparison once (meaning that the dictionary array has only one element, I think). Below is my code, please give me any advice that you might have. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class spellChecker {

    private String[] dictionaryArray; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        spellChecker spellcheck = new spellChecker();
        spellcheck.textFileRead(spellcheck.dictionaryRead());
    } 

    public String[] dictionaryRead() throws Exception
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();

        dictionaryArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        return dictionaryArray;
    }

    public void textFileRead(String [] dictionaryArray) throws Exception
    {
        // Find and read the file
        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner inputFileScan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (inputFileScan.hasNext())
        {
            String word = inputFileScan.next();
            System.out.println("word: " + word);
            binarySearch(word);
        }
        inputFileScan.close();
    }

    public void binarySearch(String word)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last  = dictionaryArray.length;
        while (first < last) {
          int mid = first + ((last - first) / 2);
          if (word.compareTo(dictionaryArray[mid]) < 0) 
          {
              last = mid;
              System.out.println("reached compare < 0");
          } 
          else if (word.compareTo(dictionaryArray[mid]) > 0) 
          {
              first = mid + 1;
              System.out.println("reached compare > 0");
          } 
          else if (word.compareTo(dictionaryArray[mid]) == 0)
          {
              System.out.println("reached compare = 0");
              break;
          }         
        }  
        if(first >= last)
            System.out.println("reached error word: " + word);
    }
} 


}
```

Comment: Looks ok, I think "\\s*" is wrong, should be "\\s+".  * allows "zero width," which is probably not at all what you want.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for catching that. It doesn't seem to want to compare the `word` variable to the `dictionaryArray` though. Is there something flawed with `binarySearch()`?

Comment: I figured out the logic error. I needed to remove the last `else` statement, and move the `println` outside of the while loop. I also added a break in the while look when `word` equals `dictionaryArray[mid]`. I updated to code, in case anyone else working on a similar project needs some examples.